# Power BI insert second line in graph based on condition

Tags: powerbi, linegraph

I have a question regarding a line graph. I have a data sheet which has a list of applicants for different events. Which looks something like this:

[image]

I want to create a graph where I see the application progress overtime (which can be done easily by adding the date column to the X-axis and the ID column to the Y-axis). But besides that I want to add a second line for each event. (So one graph which has the overall line and a line for T13, one graph with T14, etc.) How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First create separate tables for each Event using CALCULATEDTABLE in DAX

[image]

Then create relationships one-one with IDs
[image]

Create a visual by selecting ID column from each table for each event
Select Max of ID on y Axis and then rename it to TXX
[image]